# uniform and pointwise convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^z}$ , Is the family $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N^*} \}$ normal?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Study the Convergence(pointwise and uniform ) of the sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N^*}}$

Where

$$f_n(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^z}$$

Is the family $\{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N^*} \}$ normal ?

First we study the uniform convergence

We must show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}$ is uniformly convergence in $\text{Re}\  z \geq 1+ \epsilon$ where $\epsilon >0$

$$\frac{1}{n^z} = \frac{1}{e^{z\  \text {Log}\  n}} =\frac{1}{e^{x\  \text {Log}\  n}}\frac{1}{e^{i y\  \text {Log}\  n}} $$

Now $$|\frac{1}{n^z}| = \frac{1}{n^x} \leq \frac{1}{n^{\epsilon +1}} \ \ \text{if} \ \ x \geq 1 + \epsilon$$

Let $M_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\epsilon +1}}$ which is converge So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z} $ converges uniformly if $x \geq 1 + \epsilon$

Moreover since $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{n^z}|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x} \ \ \text{which converges } \ \ \forall \ x >1$$

So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^z}$ is absolutely poinwise convergent for $x > 1$

Finally How to prove that the  family is normal ?

Thank you .

Comment: Assuming the domain in question is $\{z : \operatorname{Re} z > 1\}$: It's a locally uniformly convergent sequence.